# Disable resizing caused by axis labels length

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mschart

Here's my problem, I'm making charts with the `windows.forms.datavisualisation.charting` library in a vb.net program.

I want my charts' *`X axis`* to always be the same length *(pixel wise)* because I'm lining them up vertically. The charts all have the same width and the *`X axis`* values are always the same `(hours from 0 to 24)`.

The thing is the *`Y labels`* are not all in the same format. Some are integer representing a mass, some are percentage... Which makes the strings in each *`Y axis`* labels of different length

For example:

```
Chart1 Y axis labels: 0, 1 000 000, 2000 000, ..., 10 000 000...; 
Chart2 Y axis: 2.33%, 3.45%...
```

They all have the same font and I would like to keep it like that if possible, but the length of the X axis is more important.

Any ideas? The following charts should help to explain:

First chart
[image: first chart]

Second Chart
[image: second chart]

Comment: To be clear, are you worried that the width of the Y-axis label is going to affect the overall width of the chart thus affecting the vertical alignment?  Could you left-align the Y-axis label to the right-edge of the y-axis so that the label is inside of the chart area?  Sorry, but I'm not 100% clear what it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm sorry it would be so much simpler with pictures.
Basically, the length of the Y axis labels is affecting the width of the X axis intervals. Is this clearer? And no there is no alignment property.

Comment: Can you try posting an image to another site, e.g. imgur.com, and linking it here?

Comment: I just did. Maybe it will make more sense.The links are named First chart and Second chart.